# How to hijack html form input and accurately convert the data for use in ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

In this example I use a simple form, although in reality the form is much more complex. What I want to do is to prevent the form from submitting, and gather the data it was about to submit to use in an ajax request later.

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="myform">
<input name="string_input" value="default"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

So far I have figured out that I can easily stop form submission with an on submit listener, and it also returns an event value with lots of data in it.

```
document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    return false;
};
```

But I'm not very sure how to convert that event data into json format for my ajax request.

Is there a simple way of doing this? Perhaps there is some function for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("string_input", $("[name='string_input']").val());
$.ajax({
    url: "submit.php",
    data: formData,
    type: "POST",
    error: function(e){
        console.log(e);
    },
    success: function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

There's a shorter way to do it, but you can't POST files using this approach:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "submit.php",
    data: {string_input: $("[name='string_input']").val()},
    method: "POST"
});
```

jQuery is tagged, right?

EDIT:

In case form is unpredictable...

```
var formData = new FormData();
$("#myform input, #myform textarea").each(function(){
    formData.append($(this).prop("name"), $(this).val());
})
```

> Selects all elements in form#myform element, will traverse DOM every time it is clicked.

Comment: Well as I said, the form is much more complex and it's dynamic. We can't just append a bunch of selectors, because they change. Also there is no warranty that you will get the same values as you read them again using jquery due to the way how forms use to escape special characters. And there can be hidden inputs, which may as well contain arrays. I want to capture 100% accurate data of what is going to be submitted regardless of the form elements. And preferably without making another reading. I believe that the request data itself can somehow be intercepted.

Comment: So you want a spray and pray approach? Okay, updated answer. Every time you click send, it will traverse your #myform and get the name/value of each input & textarea element.